# Can Twilio receive SMS from China?

Tags: sms, twilio

Checking out the [relevant guide page](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/cn), I see that "Two-Way SMS" is marked "No".

What exactly does this mean? Does it mean that SMS numbers are not available in China? Does is mean that a U.S. Twilio number can't receive an SMS from China? Does it mean that the [Sender ID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181088-Why-do-some-SMS-recipients-see-a-Sender-ID-that-is-not-my-Twilio-number-) will be modified when I send from my U.S. number to China?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio employee here.

You're right that we don't support two-way SMS in China currently, but you can use Twilio to purchase a Chinese phone number and use it to send SMS messages to Chinese mobile users.

Since our Chinese numbers are currently one way, the recipients of your messages will not be able to reply to them. So if you need to get some information back from your users, you might want to include a link in your message.

Note that our Chinese numbers are currently an "alpha" feature, so you will need to [contact support](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) to purchase one.

Comment: When I 'buy a number', I don't see China in the 'Country' drop down list. So how can I buy a number that can send SMS to a Chinese phone?

Comment: I have the same question as martial. Also: why would I need to buy a Chinese number to do this -- aren't I able to send a message from a US Global SMS number to a Chinese phone?

Comment: My mistake @martial - you can purchase Chinese phone numbers but you must go through our support team to do it. Our Chinese phone number support is currently in "alpha" status.

Comment: @EliRose You can indeed get the job done using international SMS